# Mock object created in private method java

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

I have to test a public method that internally calls a private method thats create an object as this.

```
class parentClass {

public parentClass(){}

public String method1(String... arguments){
               ...............
               Obj obj1 = privateMethod(String argument);
               return string;
}

private Obj privateMethod(String argument){
        ObjectNeeded2Mock obj = new ObjectNeeded2Mock();
        ........
        return Obj

}
```

How could I mock ObjectNeeded2Mock from test? I'd tried to mock the class and using @InjectMock with parentClass but it was unusefull

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Use an injectable factory to make the ObjectNeeded2Mock instead of new.